# How to use classes or locales?

Tags: isabelle

I'm trying to define a generic operations for a programming language:

```
type_synonym vname = "string"
type_synonym 'a env = "vname ⇒ 'a option"

locale language =
  fixes big_step :: "'exp × 'val env ⇒ 'val ⇒ bool" (infix "⇒" 55)
  fixes typing :: "'type env ⇒ 'exp ⇒ 'type ⇒ bool" ("(1_/ ⊢/ (_ :/ _))" [50,0,50] 50)
```

For example this is a particular language:

```
datatype foo_exp =
  FooBConst bool |
  FooLet vname foo_exp foo_exp |
  FooVar vname |
  FooAnd foo_exp foo_exp

datatype foo_val = FooBValue bool | FooIValue int
type_synonym foo_env = "foo_val env"
datatype foo_type = FooBType | FooIType
type_synonym foo_tenv = "foo_type env"

inductive foo_big_step :: "foo_exp × foo_env ⇒ foo_val ⇒ bool"
inductive foo_typing :: "foo_tenv ⇒ foo_exp ⇒ foo_type ⇒ bool"
```

How to make it an instance of `language` locale?

Is it possible to use same notation (`⇒` and `_ ⊢ _ : _`) for different languages in one theory? Could this notation be polymorphic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To specialize the parameters of a locale, you need to do an interpretation as in

```
interpretation foo: language foo_big_step foo_typing .
```

This will generate an abbreviation `foo.f` for every definition `f` in the locale `language` specialised to `foo_big_step` and `foo_typing` and every theorem `thm` of `language` becomes specialised to `foo.thm`. The mixfix syntax annotations of parameters and all constants in the locale will not be inherited.

Type classes cannot be used in this context because your locale depends on multiple type variables and type classes in Isabelle support only exactly one type variable.

If you want to use some kind of polymorphic notation for the big-step semantics and type judgements, `Adhoc_Overloading` might work, provided that Isabelle's parser can statically resolve the overloading uniquely. Here's how this might work:

```
 theory Language imports Main "~~/src/Tools/Adhoc_Overloading" begin

 type_synonym 'a env = "vname ⇒ 'a option"

 consts
   big_step :: "'exp × 'val env ⇒ 'val ⇒ bool" (infix "⇒" 55)
   typing :: "'type env ⇒ 'exp ⇒ 'type ⇒ bool" ("(1_/ ⊢/ (_ :/ _))" [50,0,50] 50)

  locale language = 
    fixes big_step :: "'exp × 'val env ⇒ 'val ⇒ bool"
    fixes typing :: "'type env ⇒ 'exp ⇒ 'type ⇒ bool"
  begin

  adhoc_overloading Language.big_step big_step
  adhoc_overloading Language.typing typing

  end
```

After the interpretation, you have to register `foo`'s semantics and type judgement constants `foo_big_step` and `foo_typing` for adhoc overloading with the syntactic constants `big_step` and `typing` again.

```
interpretation foo: language foo_big_step foo_typing .
adhoc_overloading Language.big_step foo_big_step
adhoc_overloading Language.typing foo_typing
```

So when you write

```
term "(x :: foo_exp, E) ⇒ v"
```

thereafter, Isabelle's parser will figure out by the types that this refers to `foo_big_step`, and inside the locale `Language`, `term "(x :: 'exp, E) ⇒ v"` is resolved to the locale parameter `big_step`.

This should also work for multiple interpretations of the locale `Language` provided that the types are sufficient to uniquely resolve the overloading. If not, you'll get error messages, which are not always easy to understand.

Comment: Thanks for answer! It works. But I get the following warning: "Ambiguous input⌂ produces 3 parse trees: ... Language.big_step ... Language.language.foo_big_step ... Language.language.bar_big_step ..." If I remove notation for `foo_big_step` and `bar_big_step` then I get the following error: "Unresolved adhoc overloading of constant
  big_step :: "foo.foo_exp × (char list ⇒ foo.foo_val option) ⇒ foo.foo_val ⇒ bool"
  in term "(foo.FooAnd (foo.FooBConst True) (foo.FooBConst False), e) ⇒ foo.FooBValue False"
no instances"

Comment: @Denis: I misremembered that `interpretation` does not repeat `adhoc_overlaoding` declarations. I've edited my post accordingly. You must re-issue the `adhoc_overlaoding` commands specialised to the `foo` instance after the interpretation. Then you don't need the syntax annotations on `foo_big_step` any more and syntax is no longer abiguous.